# Can I lfind a value based on two vertical lookup values?

Tags: double, vlookup, array-formulas

I was wondering if there is a solution to the following:

In a table the first two columns identify the value in the third column.

name    quarter    value
andrea  mrch       600
pete    mrch       700
andrea  jun        900
pete    jun        850

and so on with more names and more quarters.
How can I read the value for a specific name in a specific quarter?

I have tried nested if's in an arrayformula's but I can't get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your contributions. My problem is solved with a combination of Match, Index and Offset.